# Finding an operator norm in Hilbert space

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let H be Hilbert with an orthonormal basis  $(e_n)_n$. Let $(a_{ij})_{ij}$, $i,j\geq 1
$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{ j=1}^\infty a_{ij} ^2<\infty.$$
Show there exists a bounded linear operator $T:H\to H$ such that $(Te_j,e_i)=a_{ij}$ and compute the operator norm $\|T\|$

I have defined
$$Tx=  \sum_{i=1}^\infty (x, e_i) T e_i=   \sum_{j=1}^\infty  \Big(\sum_{i=1}^\infty (T e_i, e_j) (x, e_i) \Big) e_j=  \sum_{j=1}^\infty  \Big(\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} (x, e_i) \Big) e_j$$
By Parseval and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\|Tx\|^2= \sum_{j=1}^\infty  \Big|\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} (x, e_i)\Big|^2\leq \big(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |(x, e_i)|^2 \big)\big( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a^2_{ij}\big) = \|x\|^2 \big( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a^2_{ij}\big). $$

From this it follows that $T$ is bounded and we have

$$\|T\|\leq \Big( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a^2_{ij}\Big)^{1/2}. $$

Is it possible to show that

$$\|T\|\geq \Big( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a^2_{ij}\Big)^{1/2}?$$

Or How to compute $\|T\|$?

Comment: The final inequality need not be true. If $a_{11} = 1$ and $a_{22} = 2$, but $a_{ij} = 0$ elsewhere, then the resulting (finite-rank) operator has norm $2$, not $\sqrt{5}$. I'm not sure how to compute this in general though.

Comment: I doubt that you can find a closed expression for the norm $\|T\|$.