# Operator norm in Hilbert space, Schur criterion for infnite matrices

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, orthonormal

Let H be Hilbert with an orthonormal basis  $(e_n)_n$. Consider $A,B>0$ and two sequence $a_n>0, b_n>0$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i(T e_i, e_j)\leq Aa_j \quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j(T e_i, e_j)\leq Bb_i.$$
Show that $T$ extends to continuous linear operator and that  $\|T\|\leq \sqrt{AB}$

Assume that $(Te_i, e_j)=\frac{1}{j+i-1}$ prove that $\|T\|\leq \pi.$

If $(Te_i, e_j)=\frac{1}{2^{j+i-1}}$ then compute $\|T\|.$

As explained in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323155/finding-an-operator-norm-in-hilbert-space) it is possible to get that,

$$\|T\|\leq \Big( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty (Te_i, e_j)^2\Big)^{1/2}. $$

How do I move from here?